# results wont display properly

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$connection = @mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
@mysql_select_db ("streamurl" , $connection) or die ('Error in DB Connection');
$select_all= "SELECT * FROM url";
$array = mysql_query($select_all, $connection);
    if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
$mysql_query_rename = "UPDATE url SET ST_NAME='$_POST[name]', URL='$_POST[url]', ID='$_POST[id]'  WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden2]' AND ST_NAME='$_POST[hidden3]' AND URL='$_POST[hidden1]' ";  
    if(mysql_query($mysql_query_rename, $connection)){
        echo 'Changes were applied Successfully';
    } else {
        echo 'Changes Could not be Applied';
    };
    };
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($array)){
    echo "<form action=deletestation.php method=post>";
    echo "<input type=text name=id value=$show[ID] >";
    echo "<input type=text name=name value=$show[ST_NAME] >";
    echo "<input type=text name=url value=$show[URL] >";
    echo "<input name=hidden1 type=hidden value=$show[URL] >";
    echo "<input name=hidden2 type=hidden value=$show[ID] >";
    echo "<input name=hidden3 type=hidden value=$show[ST_NAME] >";
    echo "<input name=btn type=submit value=UPDATE>";   
    echo "</form>";
};
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

First of all im new to PHP and MYSQL

the above code is used to update a table in mysql database and i have echoed out the results in text boxes . there are only few information in the table ( Station name , ID and URL ). the problem is only the 1st result is updateable and the other results can not be updated . Except 1st result the other wont display the full Station name (ST_NAME) .

Kindly point out the the Error in my code.

Comment: As a side note: dont use mysql_* functions they are almost deprecated you can use PDO or mysqli. Also dont use @ because it is shutting up warnings and errors.

Comment: I highly suggest you to get a new guide to follow and learn PHP from because whatever you're using right now is highly dangerous, outdated and poorly made.

Comment: You're new but you're using code from the last century! Also, surely you can see that there's a difference between  $_POST['btn'] and $_POST[name], etc.?

Comment: As an advice, @Sithira, you should check this out: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost","Sithira","1sithiraM");
mysql_select_db ("streamurl" , $connection) or die ('Error in DB Connection');
$select_all= "SELECT * FROM url";
$array = mysql_query($select_all, $connection);
    if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
$mysql_query_rename = "UPDATE url SET ST_NAME='$_POST[name]', URL='$_POST[url]', ID='$_POST[id]'  WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]' ";  
    if(mysql_query($mysql_query_rename, $connection)){
        echo 'Changes were applied succesfully';
    } else {
        echo 'Changes Could not be Applied';
    };
    };
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($array)){
    echo "<form action=deletestation.php method=post >";
    echo "<input type=text name=id value=$show[ID] >";
    echo "<input type=text name=name value=$show[ST_NAME] >";
    echo "<input type=text name=url value=$show[URL] >";
    echo "<input name=hidden type=hidden value=$show[ID] >";
    echo "<input name=btn type=submit value=UPDATE>";   
    echo "</form>";
};

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

finally i got it working :)

Comment: there is no error. Mysql will not support and maintanance mysql_* functions anymore. You should consider using PDO or mysqli.